# ActionBarSherlock - SherlockActivity issue - Couldn't find content container view

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've done the [setup](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) as described for ActionBarSherlock. I've also added ABS as a library project and believe this is working as expected as Eclipse is finding references to class's within it's packages. I've also set the theme as required in the code and in the AndroidManifest.xml:

Code:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class TestClass extends SherlockActivity{

Context myContext;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_NoActionBar); 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.danieljgmaclean.xxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/px_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="TestClass"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However apon execution i'm getting the following exception thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find content container view
```

This is being called on:

```
com.danieljgmaclean.xxx.TestClass.onCreate(TestClass.java:23)
```

I'm running the code on a 2.3.3 emulator and i've set the target build to 4.0.3 and JDK version to 1.6.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, figured this one out myself. Seems I didn't import the library folder properly into Eclipse. I did it again this time I selected "existing source" rather than just copying and pasting the folder... hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was a "raw" folder inside res which contained the db of the app. So I just removed the folder and the actionbar worked again. Now the problem is that I need the raw...

Comment: Andrea, this post is ambiguous. Are you saying that you solved the OPs problem, or that you have a problem that is related to this? Consider revising your answer if it is an answer, or deleting it and posting it as a question if it is a question.